# There left icon and thin stripe of listview items after removing them in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have some problem. When this statement is made it will only delete textual information and images but there left icon and little stripe.

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="listview_main" data-theme="c">
 <li><a href="detail.php?id=undefined"><img src="1.src"><h1>Bla bla</h1><p>jou</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="detail.php?id=undefined"><img src="1.src"><h1>Bla bla</h1><p>jou</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="detail.php?id=undefined"><img src="1.src"><h1>Bla bla</h1><p>jou</p></a></li>
</ul>
```

Script:

```
$(".listview_main li a[href='detail.php?id=undefined']").parent().remove();
```

I just want to delete all li elements with a href="detail.php?id=undefined". How can I do this? Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
  $(".listview_main li a[href='detail.php?id=undefined']").parent().parent().remove();
```

You need to go one more perent up. Also there's no need for listview refresh.

Comment: Thank you. I had to use parent().parent().parent().remove() :-D

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a jQueryMobile issue, for the performance jQM you need to call refresh method of the list item.

```
$('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

src: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html